# Using map in Haskell

Tags: haskell, map-function

I want to use `map` to substract the average of a list from each element of a list using `map`. So far I got this function for calculating the average:

```
averageOfList :: [Float] -> Float
averageOfList [] = 0
averageOfList a = ((foldl (+) 0 a) / fromIntegral(length a))
```

The list is `[1.3,1.7,3.3,1.0,3.3]`. How exactly do I use the function for the average in `map` to subtract from each element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For people new to functional programming `map` may be one of the first concepts that they struggle with. `map` is a function that takes two parameters: a function and a list of elements.

The type signature of `map` is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. The `(a -> b)` part is the function you pass to `map`, we will call it `f`. `f` takes one value and returns another that may be of a different type. The `[a]` part is the list of elements you want to apply `f` to, we will call it `xs`. Notice how the type signature of `f` takes an `a` and the type signature of `xs` is `[a]`, the type that `f` takes must match the type of elements in `xs`. The other thing to notice is the return type of `map` is `[b]`. This matches the return type of `f`.

Here is a simple example of using map.

```hs
plusOne :: Int -> Int
plusOne x = x + 1

xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ys = map plusOne xs
```

In this case the `a` type in `map` will be `Int` and the `b` type in `map` will also be `Int`. Let's look at a case where `a` and `b` types are different.

```
-- show :: a -> String
zs = map show ys
```

In this case `a` is `Int` and `b` is `String`. We get back a list of `String`. If you are familiar with a language like Python or C, you have probably made a for loop that starts at 0 and goes to the end of the array's length and changed the elements inside. This is the same concept.

Finally, to answer your main question, you need to first apply `averageOfList` to a `[Float]`, then subtract the resulting `average` from each element in a list.

```hs
avg = averageOfList [1.3,1.7,3.3,1.0,3.3]

subAvg x = x - avg

map subAvg [0.0,2.0,3.4,5.6]
```

In this example above I have written out the name and definition of a function we want to map over a list of floats. Another strategy is define a function inline without using a name (this is called a lambda function or anonymous function).

```hs
map (\x -> x - avg) [0.0,2.0,3.4,5.6]
```

The syntax `(\x -> )` means define a function that takes one parameter and we will call it `x`, then we define a body for the function. This is a way to define a function in line and without giving it a name.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the average, you just need to define a function that subtracts that average from its argument. A straightforward example:

```
modifyList :: [Float] -> [Float]
modifyList xs = let avg = averageOfList xs
                in map (\x -> x - avg) xs
```